# Error reported when WebWorker and Dom are both introduced into tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

In the ts project, I introduced dom and WebWorker in compilerOptions -> lib of the tsconfig.json file and then compiled and reported an error.
Below is the tsconfig.json file：

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM", "WebWorker"],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The error is reported as follows:

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:5725:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'self' must be of type 'Window & typeof globalThis', but here has type 'WorkerGlobalScope & typeof globalThis'.

5725 declare var self: WorkerGlobalScope & typeof globalThis;
                 ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17364:13
    17364 declare var self: Window & typeof globalThis;
                      ~~~~
    'self' was also declared here.
```

I don't know the reason and how to fix it